# Change Label Foreground if content matches another property value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a DataGrid displaying a list of maps with some details. I'm trying to change the foreground colour of the map which is currently active but I'm struggling. I've written the following converter to check if the DataGrid item's value matches the current map's name, but I'm not sure how to pass the name of the current map from XAML.

**Converter:**

```
public class StringToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public string CurrentMapName { get; set; }
    public Color CurrentMapColor { get; set; }
    public Color OtherMapColor { get; set; }

    string _value = "";

    public StringToBrushConverter(string currentMapName, Color currentMapColor, Color otherMapColor)
    {
        CurrentMapName = currentMapName;
        CurrentMapColor = currentMapColor;
        OtherMapColor = otherMapColor;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        _value = value as string;
        return (string)value == CurrentMapName ? new SolidColorBrush(CurrentMapColor) : new SolidColorBrush(OtherMapColor);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return _value; //TODO: Will this work?
    }
}

public sealed class RaceMapColorConverter : StringToBrushConverter
{
    public RaceMapColorConverter() : base("", new Color { R = 255, G = 0, B = 0 }, new Color { R = 255, G = 255, B = 255 }) { }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MapHistory"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        HeadersVisibility="Column"
        GridLinesVisibility="None"
        CanUserSortColumns="False"
        Style="{StaticResource MapTimerDataGrid}"
        CellStyle="{StaticResource MapTimerControlCell}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Plan.Plan}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
<!-- The Binding in CurrentMapName is not valid. It says it can only be set on a dependency property but I'm not sure how to do that -->
        <conv:RaceMapColorConverter x:Key="MapColorConverter" CurrentMapName="{Binding CurrentMap.MapName}" CurrentMapColor="Red" OtherMapColor="White" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Map" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Map.MapName}" Foreground="{Binding Map.MapName, Converter={StaticResource MapColorConverter}}" Padding="0" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <!-- Other columns removed to shorten -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I'm also not sure how to implement 'ConvertBack()`. Will storing the original value in the converter work? or could a new instance be created for the same control? Am I even going about this the right way? Thought it's also worth mentioning that I'm using Caliburn.Micro just in case it has any tricks that may help. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need `ConvertBack` here, to convert from brush to map name? [remarks section of `ConvertBack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convertback?view=netcore-3.1) method tells to use `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` or `Binding.DoNothing` for such cases

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule-of-thumb you should use converters when the data conversion needs to be two-way (i.e. view-model to view and back again) and DataTriggers when it's one-way only. That answers your question about ConvertBack (which in the example you've provided never gets called anyway, in which case you can just return Binding.DoNothing).

In this particular case, however, a converter is warranted because you need to compare two bindings. Instead of writing an application-aware converter for this one very specific task, I would instead opt for a more generic MultiConverter that simply compares two values that you provide it:

```
public class EqualityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (values.Length==2) && Object.Equals(values[0], values[1]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object[] { Binding.DoNothing, Binding.DoNothing };
    }
}
```

Then back in your application you pass both of your bindings into a MultiBinding of this type and use a DataTrigger to change the map color when the result of the comparison is true:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Map.MapName}">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" /> <!-- normal map color -->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                            <Binding Path="Map.MapName" />
                            <Binding Path="CurrentMapName" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" /> <!-- other map color -->
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```